# How to count the number of elements (except one) in an array field in streaming dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.1.0.cloudera1.

I have an array in streaming dataframe, data in the array looks like below:

```
["Windows","Ubuntu","Ubuntu","Mac","Mac","Windows","Windows"]
```

I need size of this array excluding the element "Windows" i.e.

Below is the approach I followed

```
WITH os_count AS(
SELECT  
    cluster_id,
    count(e) AS cnt
FROM systems
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(all_os) exploded as e
WHERE e <> 'Windows'
GROUP BY cluster_id)

SELECT
    a.cluster_id,
    a.memory,
    a.storage,
    c.cnt
FROM
    systems a
JOIN
    os_count c
ON(a.cluster_id = c.cluster_id)
```

but for my use case I cannot have JOINs in my query as Spark structured streaming doesn't have proper support for Joins before Spark 2.3

I can do

```
SELECT SIZE(cluster.all_os) FROM systems
```

this returns 7, but I want to filter out elements with "Windows" and should return 4 instead, not sure how to proceed without performing a join!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I achieved this by writing a UDF in spark(Scala), below is the logic:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val osCountFunction: Seq[String] => Int = _.par.filter(_!="Windows").size
    val osCountUDF = udf(osCountFunction)
```

Please let me know if there's any better approach!

**EDIT 1**

Usage of UDF:

```
val inputStream = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
      .option("subscribe", topics)
      .load()
      .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[String]
      .select(from_json($"value",systemSchema).as("data"))
      .withColumn("os_count_with_udf", osCountUDF(col("data.all_os")))

inputStream.createOrReplaceTempView("data_view")
spark.sql("SELECT os_count_with_udf from data_view")
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate","false")
      .start()
```

Note: data.all_os is Array[String] type.

Comment: You'd better upgrade to 2.4.0 for https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html :)

Comment: :) I wish I could, my client's cluster is stuck with 2.1.0, I'm desperately waiting for the update.